# Imprimir Tabla Recursiva - Idparent

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que deseo es hacer un cuestionario de la siguiente manera:

**Pregunta 1**

1. Respuesta 1
2. Respuesta 2
3. Respuesta 3
4. Respuesta 4

**Pregunta 2**

1. Respuesta 1
2. Respuesta 2
3. Respuesta 3
4. Respuesta 4

estoy intentando con el siguiente codigo:

```
foreach ($data1 as $key)
{

if($key->idparent == 0 && $key->idevaluacion == 3)
{
    echo "<h3>".$key->pregunta."</h3><br>";
    foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
            if($value->idparent == 1 && $value->idevaluacion == 3){
                echo $value->pregunta."<br>";
            }
        }   
}

}
```

Pero necesito que `$value->idparent == 1` (este uno) se imprima en forma de bucle con los ID de los padres y no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @LuisVega por favor agrega el Controller, View y Model completos para poder decirte como lo vas a hacer... no es complicado lo que necesitas...

Answer (score 0):

Después de 3 días lo resolví, si por ahí alguien necesita, aunque necesita ser optimizado. pero de todos modos funciona.

```
<?php 
$padre = array();
$preguntaP = array();
foreach ($data1 as $key =>$value) 
{
    if($value->idparent == 0)
    {
        array_push($padre,$value->idpreguntaeval);        
        array_push($preguntaP, $value->pregunta);
    }
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($padre) ; $i++) 
{   
    for ($i=0; $i < count($preguntaP); $i++) 
    { 
        echo $preguntaP[$i]."<br>";
        foreach ($data1 as $key ) 
        {           
            if ($key->idparent == $padre[$i]) 
            {
                echo $key->pregunta."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Saludos.